# BigDecimal round: doubleValue() vs setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) in price values

Tags: java, bigdecimal, price

I am using all the time `BigDecimal` for prices, but I was wondering what is the best way to show this to the user.

- Is using `doubleValue()` a good way?
- Are there any differences between this two options?

Comment: Using `doubleValue()` is definitely *not* a good way. You should never never never use floating-point for money. You should use `DecimalFormat` and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is using doubleValue() a good way?

Using BigDecimal make sense if you want to avoid using `double` (or you want to control how your numbers are formatted). If you mix `BigDecimal` and `double` I don't see the point. You may as well using `double` the whole time and simplify your code.

If you want to turn the value into a String, use `toString` e.g.

```
BigDecimal bd = ...
System.out.println("bd: " + bd.toString());
```

or just

```
System.out.println("bd: " + bd);
```

If you want to use `double` you can do

```
double d = 
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d); // round to 2 decimal places
```

An example of why BigDecimal can be more error prone that double.  Both of these answers are wrong, but in the case of `BigDecimal` it's not obvious, either in code or the result which looks fine

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.00)
                             .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(49), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
                             .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(49)));
System.out.println(1.00 / 49 * 49);
```

prints

```
0.98
0.9999999999999999
```

You can fix both code, but the fact there is a problem in the first case is easily missed. Hint: using `BigDecimal.valueOf` is not the issue.  The more verbose the code (the more symbols you use), the harder it is to see the important details.

Comment: I understand that mixing the two types makes no sense, but I do several operations with the value so I want to keep the BigDecimal for this operations but in terms of showing the price to the user is there any difference? I want to print the price value with only two decimals, as is the common way to show prices

Comment: @MrGracket see my updated answer. You can use `double` as well, but for consistency I would use one or the other. If using `double` is fine for the answer, most likely you never need BigDecimal in the first place.

Comment: I can't agree with any statement that says you can use `double` (or `float`) for money.

Comment: @EJP An yet, in practice `double` is what most investment bank do as it ends up being less error prone. I know teams which have tried switching to BigDecimal found it worse than using double and switched back.

Comment: And I have known large three-letter computer companies having to engage in major rework for disregarding this advice.

Comment: @EJP The difference is; BigDecimal always produces a result which appears right even if it is wrong. double often produces a result which appears slightly wrong, but is easily fixed with rounding. If Java had C#'s builtin `decimal` I would suspect that it is the best option, but BigDecimal's lack of language support means it's harder to check it's right and the answers are not obviously wrong.

Comment: But is there any standard that everyone use? Or this is a company matter that will lead to a discussion in all projects?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: if you use BigDecimal, don't use `setScale(2, ...)`  too early or use a precision of 2 in a division. Of course that produces values that are wrong. Use `MathContext.DECIMAL64` to compare with `double`, or `DECIMAL32` to compare with `float` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis as will rounding the `double` with a `%.2f` My point is it is much harder to determine whether a BigDecimal value has a rounding error by looking at the result.

Comment: That is not the same, because the rounding happens after the fact, not during the calculation. In other words, you round the BigDecimal far too early. You should have done something like `x.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(49), MathContext.DECIMAL64).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(49)).setScale(2, ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString()` to get a proper result.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I just see this as more complex and error prone than `System.out.printf("%.2f", 1.0/49*49);` BTW Your code wouldn't compile as you have an extra `)` which is easy to do when you have a complex expression. It is easy to get the brackets in the wrong place and have it still compile, still print what looks like a valid answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Of course it looks more complex, but it is more accurate. If you leave off the `setScale(2, ...)`, the result is `0.99999999999999988`. If you leave it in, the result is `1.00`. BigDecimals are far more accurate than floating point, no matter what you think. Those teams that switched to BigDecimal and found it worse probably made similar mistakes as you did. I wrote my own BigDecimal implementation, from scratch, in a different language (Delphi), and with operator overloading it is just as easy to use as a double or a float, and not more error prone either.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: But of course no decimal or binary type can accurately divide by 49 and then multiply by it again and give exactly 1. Only Rational or BigFraction types, which internally use a numerator and a denominator, can do that.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis correct, so you have to do some rounding either way. "it is more accurate" it's no more accurate because you specially gave it the same accuracy of a double. It can easily be made more precision but either corrected solution gives the right result, so they are both completely accurate.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis the only one which made an accidental coding mistake was yourself with the brackets btw, thus illustrating my point I feel.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I typed it from scratch, not copied from code, although I did test this directly afterward. An extra `)` generates a compiler error (actually, it already shows squigglies when I'm typing, in NetBeans), so that is no problem at all. They can't produce a bad result. Your faulty logic did produce a bad result.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You can't be more accurate than the right answer. If two solution give the same output to claim one is more accurate is meaningless.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I agree that operator overloading e.g. C# style for `decimal` would help significantly.

Comment: You made the logical mistake of rounding to two places before you multiply with 49 again. That is not what happens with the doubles, so you can't simply compare the results and say: "See, BigDecimal is even less accurate". That's nonsense.

Comment: And if you don't restrict BigDecimal to `DECIMAL64` (similar precision as `double`), it is far more accurate. If I use `100` for precision, the result is: `0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999989` without the `setScale()` call, and `1.000...etc.` with it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I never said that. That wasn't my point at all.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Indeed, You have made your code far more complex for precision you are unlikely to ever need.  Needless to say it much slower as well, but it is the silent error prone nature which does BigDecimal in, in the end.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Then I misunderstood your point. Yes, it takes some time to get used to Java's BigDecimal with its function call interface (that is why mine has overloaded operators and a default precision and rounding mode as well as functions like Java), but for such applications, it is far superior to floating point, although more tedious.

Comment: In financial applications, you may need the extra precision. If you must calculate annuities and such, you don't want to be several cents, centavos, pennies or whatever beside the real value. Other systems (here in Germany at least) may require you to round up to cents, etc. before you go on with the next item on a list. That is also much easier and **less error prone** than with floating point.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis few financial applications need more than 16 digits of accuracy. Even the US national debt *estimate* in cents doesn't need it when the actual debt is always a multiple of $1 million anyway.

Comment: But even a precision of 16 is a problem. You only get that with the first value if you use `double`. Not if you calculate many values, e.g. when calculating annuities. Errors can easily add up (or not, but fact is that you can't be sure). And well, an *estimate* is just that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Annuity or similarly repeated calculations can quickly reduce the **precision** to 8 or 9 digits when you use double, which is a problem when the original value already had 8 or 9 digits. Do a few more calculations, and you really have poor precision. That won't happen with BigDecimal.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis there could be times when you can't just round the result every N calculations or use a long in which case you could use BigDecimal but I have yet to come across such a complex calculation.

Comment: As I understand after so many comments is that it would more precise use BigDecimal, but easier to user double, so I will continue with my research in this mattr but for now I will accept your answer because it fits in the problem and it explains wich solution is better

Answer (score 1):

I suggest showing setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString() to the user.